# Use index.php or call php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have been looking into back end web development for some time now I am just looking now into the best way to implement PHP in a web app.
I wanted to know, generally, what is the usual way to communicate between the front end and the back end, as I am unsure about how I am going about running PHP scripts.

I currently have an index.php file and at the end of the file I include a html file.

```
include 'home.html.php';
```

However, this approach does not allow me to easily communicate the data retrieved from a database with my javascript files, for use in angular for my web page??

The other approach I was thinking was just calling PHP scripts on the server directly from my Javascript files, but I thought this would slow page load times.

I also thought embedding PHP in the index.html file would be another way, but this retains the same problem as the first method.

Really, I just wanted to know, how it is best to design the back end web service, so that the back end and front end can best communicate to one another, so that data retrieved from a database can be displayed through javascript using angularJS, and other similar libraries.

Comment: You could start by reading this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: where does PHP fit in with MVC; I googled it a lot today but I couldn't find any examples of how to communicate between the front and back end code??

Comment: Thanks a lot @Schlaus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a PHP file in JavaScript(jQuery) using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    data: "",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',   //or GET
    success: function(data){
        //what to do when the the request is successful
    },
    fail: function (){
        // what to do if the request fails
    }
});
```

Or you can do the following if you are working on a php file:

```
<?php
    $data = "";   //this could be any string
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var phpdata = <?php echo $data; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should do it